# Admin multi property MYSQL how to connect efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named 'admin' and another 'property'.

Then 'property' may be owned by various admins.

So, what's the best manner to have it connected?

Using 'property.admin_id' = 1,2,3 is not very efficient as I cannot SELECT on WHERE when I need.

Maybe creating additional rows for each admin?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a third table `privileges` with one row per admin/property combination referenced as foreign keys.

Admins

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Ana  |
| 3  | Dan  |
```

Property

```
| id | name       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | Property 1 |
| 2  | Property 2 |
| 3  | Property 3 |
```

Privileges

```
| id | property_id | admin_id |
|----|-------------|----------|
| 1  | 1           | 1        |
| 2  | 1           | 2        |
| 3  | 2           | 2        |
| 4  | 2           | 3        |
```

Comment: That is man, simple and efficient. Lots of thanks for your help.